# setSelectedImageTintColor not working in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, ios7, uiappearance

I'm trying to `setSelectedImageTintColor` in iOS 7, but it's not working. Here's the code that I have in my `AppDelegate.m` under `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *) self.window.rootViewController;
UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;

for (UITabBarItem *item in tabBar.items)
    {
        UIImage *image = item.image;
        UIImage *correctImage = [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
        item.image = correctImage;
    }

[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:44.0/255.0 green:176.0/255.0 blue:28.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:51.0/255.0 green:51.0/255.0 blue:51.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
```

It still won't show the selectedImageTintColor. It's white when selected; gray when unselected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a known issue in iOS 7. The `tintColor` is used for the selected tab image. The `selectedImageTintColor` is completely ignored. There is no way to tint unselected tab images.

See a [discussion on the Apple Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/851126#851126) about this.

Please file a [bug report with Apple](http://bugreporter.apple.com/).

Comment: I guess you can solve this by using an `UIImage` with `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal` mode.