# Change background color of single bar bar item - swift?

Tags: swift

I have a UITabBar of which I want to change the background color of the middle item, but I can't figure out how! (I want to keep the rest of the bar the dark grey color it is).

```
 let barTintColor = UIColor(red: 54/255, green: 54/255, blue: 54/255, alpha: 1.0)
 UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = barTintColor
```

Comment: instead of using the `appearance` proxy set the `barTintColor` of the object, when you use the proxy you modify all the `UITabBar` class instances

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by inserting a new subview to your TabBar.
Please check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26753432/1938719) answer:

```
// Add background color to middle tabBarItem
let itemIndex = 2
let bgColor = UIColor(red: 0.08, green: 0.726, blue: 0.702, alpha: 1.0)

let itemWidth = tabBar.frame.width / CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count)
let bgView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(itemWidth * itemIndex, 0, itemWidth, tabBar.frame.height))
bgView.backgroundColor = bgColor
tabBar.insertSubview(bgView, atIndex: 0)
```

Hope it helps.

Edit:
If you want to change the `background image` rather than `background color`, all you have to do is change the line :

```
bgView.backgroundColor = bgColor
```

to imageView with image as background, then add it as a subview. It may look like this:

```
backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "tabBarImage"))
bgView.addSubview(backgroundView)
```

Comment: Suppose I want to change the color of the text (and image) for a particular item (not the background color). Any ideas? Thanks fengson!