# Edit background color of specific Tab bar item

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, uitabbaritem

Hey i would like to change the background Color of my center tab bar item like instagram in swift, anyone who knows how it works. I googled but can't find any helpful answer.

Comment: Set a background image of Tabbar control 'setBackgroundImage' with center color changed, make sure about sizes for color ur center/perticuler tab  background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code :

```
// Add background color to middle tabBarItem
let itemIndex = 2
let bgColor = UIColor(red: 0.08, green: 0.726, blue: 0.702, alpha: 1.0)

let itemWidth = tabBar.frame.width / CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count)
let bgView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(itemWidth * itemIndex, 0, itemWidth, tabBar.frame.height))
bgView.backgroundColor = bgColor
tabBar.insertSubview(bgView, atIndex: 0)
```

For reference you can look into these Stackoverflow posts :

- [Change background Color of One UITabBarItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410607/uitabbar-change-background-color-of-one-uitabbaritem-on-ios7/26753432#26753432)
- [Set background Color of Active Tab bar item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045147/set-background-color-of-active-tab-bar-item-in-swift)

Comment: If I use this code I get the error "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UIView' with an argument list of type '(frame: CGRect)'"

Comment: You can use "CGRect" instead of "CGRectMake"

Comment: or make following change : UIView(frame: CGRectMake(CGFloat (itemWidth * itemIndex), 0, itemWidth, tabBar.frame.height))

Comment: Try this :  UIView(frame: CGRectMake(CGFloat (CGFloat(itemWidth) * itemIndex), 0, itemWidth, tabBar.frame.height))

Comment: Solved it! Solution : let bgView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(itemWidth * CGFloat(itemIndex)),y: 0, width: CGFloat(itemWidth),height:(tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height)!))

Comment: But it doesn't change the background color :(

Comment: Clean build and then run

Comment: Solved it again! Solution: tabBar.insertSubview(bgView, atIndex: 2)

Comment: Can't vote up now! But marked it as correct answer :)

Answer (score -2):

Change Background color of tabBarItem or use Background Image and change contest according to requirement

Comment: How does this even attempt to answer the question. This is clearly a comment and not an answer.

Comment: The Problem is I don't know how to change the background color, there is no type background color for tab bar item

Comment: Use this link to perform your process in swift http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041127/ios-8-tab-bar-item-background-colour