# Change background color of UITabBarItem in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, background-color, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I just want to change the background colour of one of the tab bat items. I found many links but didn't get any help from that.

Requirement: 
[image]

And, this is the way I setup my tab bar items

```
 let myTabBarItem3 = (self.tabBar.items?[2])! as UITabBarItem
 myTabBarItem3.image = UIImage(named: "ic_center")?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
 myTabBarItem3.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "ic_center")?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
```

What I want is the black colour background for centre tab bar item.

Any idea?

**And yes it is not a duplicate**, Because the previous answered are not accurate and to add extra subview is never a good option, So expecting some good solution from friends

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the background colour of only centre `tabBarItem` you can follow below code.

**NOTE:** All the below code is used in a custom class which extends UITabBarController as:

```
class tabbarVCViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    // MARK: - ViewController Override Methods.
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        setupInitilView()
    }

    // MARK: - setup Initial View Methode.
    private func setupInitilView() {

        delegate = self

        // Sets the default color of the icon of the selected UITabBarItem and Title
        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white

        // Sets the default color of the background of the UITabBar
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white

        // Sets the background color of the selected UITabBarItem (using and plain colored UIImage with the width = 1/5 of the tabBar (if you have 5 items) and the height of the tabBar)
        //UITabBar.appearance().selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage().makeImageWithColorAndSize(color: UIColor.black, size: CGSize.init(width: tabBar.frame.width/4, height:  tabBar.frame.height))


        // Uses the original colors for your images, so they aren't not rendered as grey automatically.
        for item in self.tabBar.items! {
            if let image = item.image {

                //item.image = image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)

                item.image = image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal) //Use default image colour as grey colour and your centre image default colour as white colour as your requirement.
            }
        }

         //Change the backgound colour of specific tabBarItem.

         let itemIndex:CGFloat = 2.0

         let bgColor = UIColor.black
         let itemWidth = tabBar.frame.width / CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count)
         let bgView = UIView(frame: CGRect.init(x: itemWidth * itemIndex, y: 0, width: itemWidth, height: tabBar.frame.height))
        bgView.backgroundColor = bgColor
        tabBar.insertSubview(bgView, at: 0)

    }

    // MARK: - UITabbarController Override Methods .
    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {

    }


    // MARK: - UITabBarControllerDelegate Methods
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

        return true
    }
}
```

Use `tabBarItem` images default colour as grey according to your UI and centre `tabBarItem` image default colour as white colour in Asset.

And you will want to extend the UIImage class to make the plain colored image with the size you need:

```
extension UIImage {
    func makeImageWithColorAndSize(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image!
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you.. i have already gone through this answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31680820/4033273. This answer is for selected tab bar item

Comment: So this approach is not working for you, if not than can you please show your code where you use above code

Comment: @Moin Shirazi Check the updated answer.

Comment: @Moin Shirazi Check the updated answer for achieve only centre UITabBarItem as black.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a subview to the parent tabBar
Then you can set a background color on the subview. 
Calculating the offset and width of your tabBarItem and inserting the subView under it.

```
let itemIndex = 2
let bgColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0)

let itemWidth = tabBar.frame.width / CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count)
let bgView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(itemWidth * itemIndex, 0, itemWidth, tabBar.frame.height))
bgView.backgroundColor = bgColor
tabBar.insertSubview(bgView, atIndex: 0)
```

Comment: Thanks you.. i have already gone through this answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/26753432/4033273

Comment: Any other better option?

Answer (score 0):

You can use imageView to achieve this affect , try this approach

```
let myImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    return imageView
}()

// Now add this imageView as subview and apply constraints
tabbar.addSubview(myImageView)
myImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false        
addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[v0(28)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": myImageView]))
addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[v0(28)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": myImageView]))

tabbar.myImageView.image = UIImage(named: "ic_center")?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)
tabbar.myImageView.tintColor = UIColor.black
```

Comment: what is addconstraints here??

Comment: this method will add constraints on a view ,

Comment: That i know but what is the use here

Comment: This method will be called on the parent view of imageView , I assumed it as tabbar

Comment: These constraints will set the frame only then we can see the imageView on screen

Comment: its not working

Comment: Can you show the code that you tried?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150194/discussion-between-moin-shirazi-and-user1000).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.pink
 UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.white
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
let x = Double(UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 5.0)
let y = Double(tabBarController!.tabBar.frame.size.height)
let indicatorBackground: UIImage? = self.image(from: UIColor.black, for: CGSize(width: x, height: y))
UITabBar.appearance().selectionIndicatorImage = indicatorBackground
```

**Helper Methods**

```
func image(from color: UIColor, for size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    autoreleasepool {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
    }
    let context: CGContext? = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    context?.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
    context?.fill(rect)
    let image: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image!
}
```